# SQL Server : smallest ROW_NUM in where condition, with subgroup pre-condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, logic, row-number

Thanks all in advance! I am trying to describe this as clear as I can.

I got two sub-tables, 1st table retrieves `Comfirmed_Date` and the 2nd table retrieves `Mail_Date` with condition `Mail_Date >= Comfirmed_Date`.

```
select
    a.ID
    ,g.ROWNUM
    ,f.CORM_DT
    ,g.MAIL_DT
from 
    SOURCE_U a
left join 
    (select 
         a.SOURCE_ID
         , Max(Cast(b.ATUF_DATE3 as date)) as [CORM_DT]
     from
         ATTACH_U a
     inner join 
         USERFLD_D b on a.DEST_CK = b.DEST_CK 
     group by 
         a.SOURCE_ID) f on f.SOURCE_ID = a.SOURCE_ID 
left join 
    (select 
         a.SOURCE_ID
         , cast(b.MAILED_DT as date) as MAIL_DT
         , row_number() over (partition by SOURCE_ID order by CREATE_DT) as ROWNUM
     from 
         ATTACH_U a
     left join 
         LETTER_D b on b.DEST_CK = a.DEST_CK) g on g.SOURCE_ID = a.SOURCE_ID 
                                                and g.MAIL_DT >= f.CORM_DT
```

I need the first line (smallest `row_num`) for the tables, how can I achieve that?

Original I think I can make condition like

```
where g.ROWNUM = 1
```

but because I have the condition on joint table, it does not work for below situations.

```
ID              gROWNUM             CORM_DT                   MAIL_DT 
1001               3                2020-10-20                2020-10-22               
1001               4                2020-10-20                2020-10-30
1002               2                2020-10-20                2020-10-21               
1002               3                2020-10-20                2020-10-23
1002               4                2020-10-20                2020-10-28               
1003               1                2020-10-20                2020-10-30
1004               1                2020-10-20                2020-10-21               
1004               2                2020-10-20                2020-10-23
1005               4                2020-10-20                2020-10-28               
1006               1                2020-10-20                2020-10-30
```

I only want one line for each ID here.

Comment: Sort by `gROWNUM` and `SELECT TOP 1...`

Comment: @CriticalError So sorry I still not make it clear, it contains multi IDs...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    a.ID
    , g.ROWNUM
    , f.CORM_DT
    , g.MAIL_DT
FROM SOURCE_U a 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        a.SOURCE_ID
        , Max(Cast(b.ATUF_DATE3 as date)) as [CORM_DT]
    FROM ATTACH_U a
    INNER JOIN USERFLD_D b 
        ON a.DEST_CK = b.DEST_CK 
    GROUP BY a.SOURCE_ID
    
) f 
    ON f.SOURCE_ID = a.SOURCE_ID 
LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT 
        a.SOURCE_ID
        , CAST( b.MAILED_DT AS date) AS MAIL_DT
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SOURCE_ID ORDER BY CREATE_DT ) AS ROWNUM
    FROM ATTACH_U a
    LEFT JOIN LETTER_D b 
        ON b.DEST_CK = a.DEST_CK

) g
    ON g.SOURCE_ID = a.SOURCE_ID 
    AND g.MAIL_DT >= f.CORM_DT
ORDER BY
    g.ROWNUM;
```

Comment: Thanks and I am so sorry I still not make it clear, it contains multi IDs. I've re-editing my question

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a window function in your select.

```
select rows, columns... from (
select dense_rank() over ( partition by a.ID order by MAIL_DT) as rows, columns...
...
)
where rows = 1
```